# Plotly hover to show multiple values in pie chart

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a pie chart using a dataframe that shows breakdown data on hover.

The dataframe I am using is similar to the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px  

d = {'Customer': ['Cust 1', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 3', 'Cust 3','Cust 4', 'Cust 4', 'Cust 5', 'Cust 4','Cust 5', 'Cust 6', 'Cust 6', 'Cust 6'], 
         'Product': ['DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE'], 
         'PO': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14', 'P15', 'P16'],
         'Revenue': [100, 120, 240, 200, 110, 100, 120, 180, 100, 120, 240, 200, 110, 100, 120, 180]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
fig = px.pie(d, values='Revenue', names='Product')
fig.show()
```

This produces a pie chart AOK, but what I am wanting to do is, on hover, show a breakdown of each customer and their Revenue for the Product.

So each hover would have a list of each customer that bought the product, and their total revenue. For example if you hovered over Digital, the hover box would show:

```
Digital
Cust 1: 420
Cust 2: 110
Cust 3: 300
Cust 4: 420
Cust 6: 220
```

Any help will be appreciated. Im new to Plotly, so not exactly sure how to ask the question, let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: I am not sure of the specific output, but if you have two categorical variables, the sunburtst graph is the best choice. Try this. `fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['Product','Customer'], values='Revenue')`

Comment: When I try that, I get an error ```TypeError: sunburst() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'``` - I have the latest version of plotly installed, so not sure how to fix

Comment: @DavidWarren I wrote an answer, check if it works. If not, I can try to find the error and update the answer if required.

Comment: Thanks Dapper, I managed to produce the same results by changing my instance of Plotly. Looking at the output though, its not quite what I need (it is for a presentation, so needs to be simple) - is there no way to have the Children elements as a list in the hover, rather than in the chart itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such capability in plotly as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you can't split pie charts in plotly. An alternative is the sunburst chart. This can show hierarchical data, which fits in this situation where there are multiple customers for each product. Here is an example with the provided data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px  

d = {'Customer': ['Cust 1', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 3', 'Cust 3','Cust 4', 'Cust 4', 'Cust 5', 'Cust 4','Cust 5', 'Cust 6', 'Cust 6', 'Cust 6'], 
         'Product': ['DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE', 'DIGITAL', 'DIGITAL', 'STORE'], 
         'PO': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14', 'P15', 'P16'],
         'Revenue': [100, 120, 240, 200, 110, 100, 120, 180, 100, 120, 240, 200, 110, 100, 120, 180]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.sunburst(df, values='Revenue', path=['Product','Customer'])
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]